# asp.net core database location and messaging

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sqlite, asp.net-core

I am learning asp.net core 1.0.1 and I have successfully connected to an SQLite database. The connection string is saved in `appsettings.json`. I put the same database, one in the bin folder and  one in the netcoreapp1.0.

I can create a new record and it gets saved. I checked both databases using SQLite manager in Firefox to see which one is being used but there is no saved data on both of them.

1. So where is the database that I am working on saved?
2. I tried to use some kind of messageBox to show the connection string path but there's no message box in asp.net core. How can I show messages in asp.net core?

   ```
    // appsettings.json
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "MyDatabase": "Data Source=MyDb.sqlite"
    }
   ```

Comment: You need to post the relevant code.

Comment: Slightly improved formatting

Comment: hi Yaz. When you say "I can create a new record and it gets saved." how did you prove that the record was saved? Did you stop the app, restart it and then retrieve the record?

Comment: While the app is running, I open SQLite database in Firefox SQLite manager and see the record is saved. SQLite db is in bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can output your connection string from your appsettings.json into your view.

First this is how my connection string is defined in the appsettings.json

```
"database": {
"connection": "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=OdeToFood;Integrated  Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
```

}

Create a class to store the connection string

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CoreTest
{
    public class AppSettings
    {
        public string connection { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Update the startup.cs file

Ensure the constructor is reading the appsettings.json file

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
```

Add these lines to ConfigureServices

```
 services.AddOptions();
 services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("database"));
```

Update the controller

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private AppSettings _AppSettings;

    public HomeController(IOptions<AppSettings> settings)
    {
        _AppSettings = settings.Value;
    }
```

Add the controller method

```
 public async Task ContentAction()
    {
        var constr = _AppSettings.connection;
        var jsonString = "{\"connectionString\""+ constr + "}";
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);
        Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        await Response.Body.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
```

Call the controller method from your view

```
 <div>
    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="ContentAction" class="btn btn-  success confirmCreate">
        Generate Response
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Output the connection string

```
{"connectionString"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=OdeToFood;Integrated     Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False}
```

Comment: Thanks pforsthoff, I am working on your code. I will post back when I am done. :-)

Comment: Your code works perfectly for the task. I've learned quite new things from you. I am very grateful for your help. All the best.

Comment: Yaz, can you please mark this answer as useful? Actually both of them if they were helpful. Thank You!

Comment: I did but it says it says vote has been recorded and votes less than 15 etc.. Thanks

Comment: I am new here, I did what I said above, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to output something quick to the response body you can add a method on your controller like this...

```
public async Task ContentAction()
{
    var jsonString = "{\"test\":1,\"output\":false}";
    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);
    Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    await Response.Body.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

You can then call this controller method from your view like this...

```
<div>
    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="ContentAction" class="btn btn-success confirmCreate">
        Generate Response
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

This will output values like this..

```
{"test":1,"value":false}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I tried your code as is and it works. But I need to show the connection string so I did this: string connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDatabase");
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(connection);
            Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            await Response.Body.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length); but I get ArgumentNullException: String reference not set to an instance of a String. Parameter name: s

Answer (score 0):

Well in the end the database is actually saved in bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0.(I was looking in the wrong folder).

But I still don't know how to show a simple message in asp.net core!

I am learning asp.net core + loads of other things just to create an asp.net database driven website, but it's not easy. simple things are hard to implement.

Using wpf, c# + mvvm is great, I wish I could use them instead for web development. But hey we live and learn. :-)

Thanks.